# Show/Export every folder thats linked with a specific AD-Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a command that read all the folders and files that linked with a AD-Group?
For example: We have in our company many folders and many AD-Groups. The guys who created this big and confusing construct are all retired. Now I have many groups that had no description and I want to find out which group is on which folder on our netdrives. Any ideas?

Comment: You start with something like this Get-ChildItem -path "\\server\path" -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object { get-acl $_.FullName }

Comment: Thanks! but it only shows the group "File-Admins" with Full-Access. All the other groups are not there and I can´t fix it. Hmm... any idea?